# Creating temporary threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading

How do I implement temporary threads in java, such that they invoke a function in a separate thread(communicate/send packet to another thread) and then terminate while the other threads keep running?

Comment: You create a thread object and start it. Or use a factory. What have you tried?

Comment: I've tried creating a thread object but I don't know how to safely terminate a thread and how to make it communicate with another thread.

Comment: First, all threads are temporary. Second, a factory is used to create objects. You would have a method in another class calling the factory for a new thread. Third, you terminate a thread by calling...wow I didn't know `Thread.stop()` was deprecated. Set the thread to null or follow [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) made by oracle.

Comment: What you describe in your question is using a thread to execute a _task_.  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.  If your program has a lot of tasks to execute, then you might be better of using a _thread pool_ to execute them.  Read about `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` and related standard library classes to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

Try This one

```
Thread t = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
       //Thread Implmentation code here
    }

}

t.start();
```

Comment: The code above simply creates a thread, right? Please explain how the thread will communicate with a separate thread.

Comment: It depends what do you want to do. please provide details.

Answer (score 0):

The api for creating a thread is using the class Thread. you can override the `run` method or you can pass a Object that implements the `Runnable` interface and pass to a thread when creating it. `Thread.start` schedules the thread for execution.

Threads in the same JVM can communicate via shared objects; i.e. **you pass a Object to a thread and you can use it as a shared state**. You call the shared object methods to change the state seen by the various threads.  When multiple threads communicate each other with one or more shared object you need to assure that the modifications to the object are made in a thread-safe way since the invocations on the shared object can happen concurrently.

The basic api for regulating access to the shared objects are the use of the `synchronized` keyword and the `wait` and `notify` and `notifyAll` methods methods of the Object class.

[Here is the Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) on Java concurrency; whe you can find detailed information. over the years Java has evolved in order to make concurrency and synchronization easier to use; there are a lot of classes in the JDK to deal with concurrent operations.